# How to write aggregation results to database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need update current records based on aggregation results on this records.
query:

```
db.customer.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "LOAN.AMOUNT": {$exists: true}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "FIRST_NAME": 1,
            "SECOND_NAME": 1,
            "LOAN.AMOUNT": {$subtract : [{$sum : "$LOAN.AMOUNT"},{$multiply : [{$sum : "$LOAN.AMOUNT"}, 0.05]}]},
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

I have to use mongoDB shell for queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the document(s) using the `forEach` [cursor method](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach) where you can specify the update operation on each document of the aggregation result (which is a cursor with documents).

```
db.customer.aggregate( [
    {
        $match: {
            "LOAN.AMOUNT": {$exists: true}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "FIRST_NAME": 1,
            "SECOND_NAME": 1,
            "LOAN.AMOUNT": {$subtract : [{$sum : "$LOAN.AMOUNT"},{$multiply : [{$sum : "$LOAN.AMOUNT"}, 0.05]}]}
        }
    }
] ).forEach( doc => db.customer.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { "LOAN.AMOUNT": doc.LOAN.AMOUNT } } )
```

If you are using MongoDB version 4.2+, you can use [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#updatemany-behavior-aggregation-pipeline), which *uses an aggregation for the update* operation:

```
db.customer.updateMany(
  { "LOAN.AMOUNT": { $exists: true } },
  [
    { $set: { 
           "LOAN.AMOUNT": { 
                $subtract : [ { $sum: "$LOAN.AMOUNT" }, { $multiply: [ {$sum: "$LOAN.AMOUNT" }, 0.05 ] } ] 
           }
    } }
  ]
)
```

Comment: [js] WriteError: cannot compare to undefined :

WriteError({

 "index" : 0,

 "code" : 2,

 "errmsg" : "cannot compare to undefined",

 "op" : {

  "q" : {

   "_id" : undefined

  },

  "u" : {

   "$set" : {

    "LOAN.AMOUNT" : 19000

   }

  },

  "multi" : false,

  "upsert" : false

 }

})

Comment: ok, I remove "_id": 0 from $project and now it's seems like works.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The `_id` is required to update the collection in the `forEach`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `pretty()` you can use `forEach()`, something like that, I don't know your field names:

```
forEach(function(result) {
    db.customer.updateOne(
      { "FIRST_NAME": result["FIRST_NAME"] },
      { "SECOND_NAME": result["SECOND_NAME"] },
      { $set: { "LOAN.AMOUNT": result["LOAN.AMOUNT"] } }
    );
});
```

Comment: [js] Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators :

Comment: It's actually syntax issue, try `result.fieldname` instead of `result["fieldname"]`

Answer (score 1):

The [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) operator can be used as the last stage of an aggregation pipeline to write the results to a collection.

**Capabilities:**

- Available starting in MongoDB 4.2
- Can output to a collection in the same or different database.
- Creates a new collection if the output collection does not already exist.
- Can incorporate results (insert new documents, merge documents, replace documents, keep existing documents, fail the operation, process documents with a custom update pipeline) into an existing collection.
- Can output to a sharded collection. Input collection can also be sharded.
- Corresponds to SQL statements:

  - MERGE.
  - INSERT INTO T2 SELECT FROM T1.
  - SELECT INTO T2 FROM T1.
  - Create/Refresh Materialized Views.

The [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator is similar, but it will completely replace the target collection with the aggregation results